# Eclipse-HTTP Status 404

Tags: jsp, struts2

I know that someone already asked this, but I haven't got the answer I wanted. So i'm trying to run a JSP page using Tomcat, but I keep getting the following error message:

```
HTTP Status 404 - /LoginWeather/

type Status report

message /LoginWeather/

description The requested resource is not available.
```

---

Apache Tomcat/7.0.39

The server is configured correctly, localhost:8080 is functional. Here is my web.xml and my .jsp files content:
web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>LoginWeather</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>login.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

login.jsp:``

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Welcome</title>
</head>
<body>
<s:form>
    <s:textfield label="Username" key="userName"/>
    <s:password label="Password" key="password"/>
    <s:submit/>
</s:form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try `http://localhost:8080/LoginWeather/login.jsp`

Comment: When you run only the JSP, then the url is the one that you gave and I already tried that. The same error comes up.

Comment: I don't know where you put your JSP, 404 means that your JSP is not existed.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `index.jsp` with following content:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0;URL=login.action"/>
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
```

Then your `web.xml` will look that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>LoginWeather</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

After loading `index.jsp` there will be automatic redirection to `login.jsp`.

You can also try to display `login.jsp` by typing `http://localhost:8080/LoginWeather/login.action` into your browser.

Comment: It doesn't matter what you name your welcome page. It should also run if I right click on my login.jsp code and select Run as-> Run on server...

Comment: But this is important how you want to access to your jsp page. In struts 2 typing login.jsp will not work untill u won't use action mapping - login.action. So I offered firing login.action automatically...